# Cannot import name PlayBook

Tags: python, apache-cloudstack

I am setting up Apache CloudStack 4.5 on my VM, which is running CentOS 6.7 with hypervisor Oracle VM VirtualBox.

After I have downloaded all the files from GitHub and set up the environment of CloudStack, I executed `python /root/cldstk-deploy/cldstkdeploy.py --get all`, `python /root/cldstk-deploy/cldstkdeploy.py --setup all` and everything worked fine.

But when I execute `python /root/cldstk-deploy/cldstkdeploy.py` to do the all-in-one deployment, I get the error cannot import name PlayBook after I say yes to start the installation.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what the error is, you won't be able to run a KVM hypervisor in Oracle VM Virtual Box as [it does not support "nested" virtualization](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032).

In order for nested virtualization to work, OVM must expose the "vmx" CPU flag on Intel, and something equivalent on AMD-V.

The only other desktop virtualization platforms that support this are VMware Workstation and Parallels (to best of my knowledge - but don't trust me, check for yourself).